# Determine whether a matrix is diagonalizable without knowing the matrix components

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove that $A$ is diagonalizable when I already know this:

- $A$ is $7 \times 7.$
- Rank$(A) = 4.$
- It's characteristic polynomial is $t^3(t^2-2)(t^2-5).$

Now I know that $0$ is eigenvalue with both algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity of $3$,
and I know that $\sqrt{2}$ is eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of $2$ and $\sqrt{5}$ is eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of 2.
Can I know the geometric multiplicity of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ without knowing the actual matrix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\sqrt2$ is not with algebraic multiplicity of $2$.

Comment: Instead, $\sqrt2$ and $-\sqrt2$ are two distinct eigenvalues, each with multiplicity $1$.

Comment: All nonzero eigenvalues ($\sqrt{2},- \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}, -\sqrt{5}, $) appear once.

Comment: The only eigenspace in question is that corresponding to $0$ and this has dimension $3$.

Comment: Stupid me, thank you. But in general it is possible to determine if A is diagonalizable if I know only the characterized polynom and DON'T know the geometric multiplicity of a eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity that is bigger then 1?

Comment: @Avishay28: No.

Comment: @Avishay28 No. For example both the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 &1\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 &1\end{pmatrix}$$
have polynomial $(1-t)^2$, but the first is diagonal(izable), and the second isn't diagonalizable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the eigenvalues $ \pm \sqrt 2$ and $\pm \sqrt 5$ appear with algebraic multiplicity $1$, which means they must also have geometric multiplicity $1$.  The only potentially troublesome eigenvalue is $0$.

The algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $3$ (since this is the exponent of $t$ in the polynomial). The geometric multiplicity is also the dimension of the nullspace of $A - 0I$, i.e. the nullspace of $A$.  However, $A$ has rank $4$, which by the rank-nullity theorem means that the nullspace has dimension $7-4 = 3$. So, the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $3$, which coincides with the algebraic multiplicity.

Conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable, since all eigenvalues have geometric multiplicity equal to their algebraic multiplicity.